# Context Registered BroadcastReceiver in Android Oreo - when app not in foreground

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

Pre-Oreo, I had a background service which I would start, and it would context-register a few BroadcastReceivers.

When one of the receivers receives an intent, it would process it within the service.

Example:
When it receives android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED, turn on WiFi.

The problem is, with the new background limitations, my service will be shut down shortly after my app is closed.

I can solve the problem with a foreground service, but the user doesn't need to see a notification all the time.

The [Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#migration) suggests using the job scheduler to poll for the state which would have triggered the implicit intent.  This seems much more wasteful than registering the receiver in the background service.  The service isn't actually doing anything until one of the receivers is triggered.

What is the new proper way to listen for Bluetooth Disconnection and react immediately? (without your app in the foreground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found there is a short [white-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html) of implicit intents which may still be registered in the manifest.  So although the service won't continue running, I can refactor and use implicit intent filters with a manifest registered BroadcastReceiver.

This doesn't solve all my problems as some of my events aren't on the white-list, but at least I can maintain the majority of my functionality.

The actions I'm still missing are PHONE_STATE and HEADSET_PLUG.  I'll update this post if I find a solution for those.

Comment: It appears PHONE_STATE is now whitelisted